# How do negative-sized rectangles intersect?

Tags: c#, intersection

Can someone explain why negatively sized `Rectangle`s intersect the way they do?

```
var r  = new Rectangle(0, 0,  3,  3);
var r0 = new Rectangle(0, 0, -1, -1);
var r1 = new Rectangle(1, 1, -1, -1);
var r2 = new Rectangle(2, 2, -1, -1);
var r3 = new Rectangle(3, 3, -1, -1);

System.Console.WriteLine(r.IntersectsWith(r0)); // False
System.Console.WriteLine(r.IntersectsWith(r1)); // False
System.Console.WriteLine(r.IntersectsWith(r2)); // True
System.Console.WriteLine(r.IntersectsWith(r3)); // False
```

I would think `r1` and `r2` should always intersect with `r`, even though they don't. `r3` should intersect if you consider their negative size. If negative sizes aren't considered, `r0` should intersect.

Why does this work the way it does, and what other caveats I should look for when working with `Rectangle` structures?

Comment: I have no idea... I guess the behaviour of IntersectsWith is undefined for negatively-sized rectangles, allthough it's not documented as such in the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx)... I suggest you post this question to MSDN as "community content"? It's a REALLY good question. One suspects that the behaviour of negatively-sized Rectangle's is not defined for all there spatial operations... Are they even rendered as you'd expect?

Comment: @corlettk: "Community Content" is **not** intended for posting questions. That's what the MSDN forums are for.

Comment: Thanx Cody. I've never used MSDN's forums ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create a rectangle with a negative width, then it draws a rectangle that starts at the original (x,y) point and draws to the left instead of to the right.

If you create a rectangle with a negative height, then it draws a rectangle that starts at the original (x,y) point and draws to up instead of down.

Thus if you make a rectangle of with say `new Rectangle(5, 4, -1, -2);` then you get a rectangle with the following points: (5,4), (4,4), (5,2), (4,2).

Run the following code for an example:

```
    Rectangle negWidthHeightRect = new Rectangle(5, 4, -1, -2);
    Console.WriteLine(negWidthHeightRect.Left);
    Console.WriteLine(negWidthHeightRect.Right);
    Console.WriteLine(negWidthHeightRect.Bottom);
    Console.WriteLine(negWidthHeightRect.Top);
    Console.WriteLine(negWidthHeightRect.Width);
    Console.WriteLine(negWidthHeightRect.Height);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is as follows:

```
5
4
2
4
-1
-2
```

The behavior is somewhat expected given Microsoft's comments on other rectangle-like controls (besides System.Drawing.Rectangle).  See MSDM [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Now, why does the rectangle's `IntersectsWith` method produce such weird results.  It is because it is using the following code for implementing the `IntersectsWith` method:

```
public bool IntersectsWith(Rectangle rect)
{
    return ((((rect.X < (this.X + this.Width)) && (this.X < (rect.X + rect.Width))) && (rect.Y < (this.Y + this.Height))) && (this.Y < (rect.Y + rect.Height)));
}
```

If you follow through the logic yourself you will see why you get the answers you get.  What Microsoft should probably do is either:

1) when it sees a negative width/height make the width/height positive and readjust the Left/Top

2) Or in the IntersectsWith logic, they should do some Min(x, x+width) and Min (y, y+width) when doing the logic.

Some others smarter than me may have an even more clever way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first comment to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384468/rectangles-parsing-in-vb-net).  It appears to be saying that the negative height and width represent a rectangle drawn in the quadrant that's above and to the left of the current coordinate.

Comment: which would mean that `Rectangle(0, 0,  -x,  -x)` is the same as `Rectangle(-x, -x,  x,  x)`.

Comment: @Dan D.  Seems to me that's true.  It came as a total surprise to me that it was even valid input.  They talk about `ScreenToClient` and `ClientToScreen` in that answer (which I personally don't have a lot of experience with), which leads me to believe its a part of their internal machinations.

Comment: @Dan D. Does this imply `Rectangle(1, 1, -1, -1)` is the same as `Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)`? If so, it should still intersect with `r`.

Comment: @Daniel Rasmussen `Rectangle(-1,-1,-1,-1)` is the same as `Rectangle(0,0,1,1)`